# Why is populating a Vec via replacing defaults so much faster than populating something with preset capacity?

Tags: vector, rust

Foreword: I am generally not an optimizer.

Most times, when solving a coding puzzle in Rust, I use `Vec::with_capacity` to initialize my vectors, and then insert items by `push`ing them onto the vector. For most purposes, this was fine, but I recently encountered a puzzle that required a faster program, which inspired me to rethink my approach.

Since I know the capacity of the vector is exactly some number, I decided to compare the results of my usual `with_capacity` and `push` approach, to creating a vector full of 0's and replacing them instead. This is the code I used to benchmark the two operations:

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use test::Bencher;

    // Create a vector with a capacity of 10,000 u16s
    // and populate it by pushing.
    #[bench]
    fn push_fill(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut v: Vec<u16> = Vec::with_capacity(10000);
            for i in 0..10000 as u16 {
                v.push(i);
            }
        })
    }

    // Create a vector of 10,000 u16s, initialize them
    // to 0, and then replace them to populate the vector.
    #[bench]
    fn replace_fill(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut v: Vec<u16> = vec![0u16; 10000];
            for i in 0..10000 {
                v[i] = i as u16;
            }
        })
    }
}
```

To my surprise, the replacement solution is an order of magnitude better than the `with_capacity` solution when I run `cargo +nightly bench`.

```
   Compiling benchmarks v0.1.0 (file:///C:/Users/CEUser/Documents/Programs/rustprojects/benchmarks)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 10.75 secs
     Running target\release\deps\benchmarks-0b553bf1dfb7e9a4.exe

running 2 tests
test tests::push_fill    ... bench:      26,756 ns/iter (+/- 4,046)
test tests::replace_fill ... bench:       1,902 ns/iter (+/- 802)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured; 0 filtered out
```

I was surprised at the difference in time, especially given that I expected the `replace` version to take longer (given that it has to create a vector full of filler, and *then* replace that filler data with actual data).

Is there an intuitive reason why `replace_fill` is so much faster than `push_fill`? What's the difference between what the two functions are doing?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to make much difference, but your two loops aren't the same. One iterates over `usize`s and one iterates over `i16`s

Comment: Switching to `0..10000 as u16` and `v[i as usize]` in `replace_fill` has little impact - `push_fill` gives `30,213 ns/iter (+/- 12,046)` and `replace_fill` gives `1,982 ns/iter (+/- 2,291)`.

Comment: `Vec.push()` has logic that increments the `len` field of the `Vec` and checks if capacity needs to be grown.  The range checks in `replace_fill()` could potentially be optimized out, and the second pass over the memory is probably insignificant thanks to cache.

Comment: And creating the vector with 10000 times `0u16` is only either `malloc` + `memset` or in this case maybe even just one `calloc(10000, sizeof(uint16_t))` – so nothing time-consuming.

Comment: Well, @KBiermann, sounds good to me. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, check the assembly!

You can use [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/6rnu4y) or the playground; though I prefer godbolt here as it uses highlighting to match the assembly sections to the source code, making it easier to explore.

---

In the link above, the `replace_fill` function is optimized to:

```
example::replace_fill:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 48
  lea rdx, [rbp - 24]
  mov edi, 20000
  mov esi, 2
  call __rust_alloc_zeroed@PLT
  test rax, rax
  je .LBB3_4
  movdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI3_0]
  mov ecx, 32
  movdqa xmm1, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI3_1]
  movdqa xmm2, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI3_2]
  movdqa xmm3, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI3_3]
  movdqa xmm4, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI3_4]
  movdqa xmm5, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI3_5]
.LBB3_2:
  movdqu xmmword ptr [rax + 2*rcx - 64], xmm0
  movdqa xmm6, xmm0
  paddw xmm6, xmm1
  movdqu xmmword ptr [rax + 2*rcx - 48], xmm6
  movdqa xmm6, xmm0
  paddw xmm6, xmm2
  movdqu xmmword ptr [rax + 2*rcx - 32], xmm6
  movdqa xmm6, xmm0
  paddw xmm6, xmm3
  movdqu xmmword ptr [rax + 2*rcx - 16], xmm6
  movdqa xmm6, xmm0
  paddw xmm6, xmm4
  movdqu xmmword ptr [rax + 2*rcx], xmm6
  paddw xmm0, xmm5
  add rcx, 40
  cmp rcx, 10032
  jne .LBB3_2
  mov esi, 20000
  mov edx, 2
  mov rdi, rax
  call __rust_dealloc@PLT
  add rsp, 48
  pop rbp
  ret
.LBB3_4:
  mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 24]
  movups xmm0, xmmword ptr [rbp - 16]
  movaps xmmword ptr [rbp - 48], xmm0
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 24], rax
  movaps xmm0, xmmword ptr [rbp - 48]
  movups xmmword ptr [rbp - 16], xmm0
  lea rdi, [rbp - 24]
  call __rust_oom@PLT
  ud2
```

The latter section (LBB3_4) is OOM handling, so never used. Therefore, the flow of execution goes:

- `example::replace_fill`, which does the allocation + initial setup,
- `.LBB3_2` which is the loop.

There are 2 elements of note:

- No `Vec` code appears there, at all,
- Those are vector instructions.

---

On the other hand, `push_fill` is a tad more complicated:

```
example::push_fill:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  push r15
  push r14
  push rbx
  sub rsp, 40
  lea rdx, [rbp - 48]
  mov edi, 20000
  mov esi, 2
  call __rust_alloc@PLT
  mov rcx, rax
  test rcx, rcx
  je .LBB2_11
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 48], rcx
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 40], 10000
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 32], 0
  xor r15d, r15d
  lea r14, [rbp - 48]
  xor esi, esi
.LBB2_2:
  mov ebx, r15d
  add bx, 1
  cmovb bx, r15w
  jb .LBB2_3
  cmp rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 40]
  jne .LBB2_9
  mov rdi, r14
  call <alloc::raw_vec::RawVec<T, A>>::double
  mov rcx, qword ptr [rbp - 48]
  mov rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 32]
.LBB2_9:
  mov word ptr [rcx + 2*rsi], r15w
  mov rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 32]
  inc rsi
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 32], rsi
  movzx eax, bx
  cmp eax, 10000
  mov r15w, bx
  jb .LBB2_2
.LBB2_3:
  mov rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 40]
  test rsi, rsi
  je .LBB2_5
  add rsi, rsi
  mov rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 48]
  mov edx, 2
  call __rust_dealloc@PLT
.LBB2_5:
  add rsp, 40
  pop rbx
  pop r14
  pop r15
  pop rbp
  ret
.LBB2_11:
  movups xmm0, xmmword ptr [rbp - 40]
  movaps xmmword ptr [rbp - 64], xmm0
  movaps xmm0, xmmword ptr [rbp - 64]
  movups xmmword ptr [rbp - 40], xmm0
  lea rdi, [rbp - 48]
  call __rust_oom@PLT
  ud2
  mov rbx, rax
  lea rdi, [rbp - 48]
  call core::ptr::drop_in_place
  mov rdi, rbx
  call _Unwind_Resume@PLT
  ud2
```

More blocks, meaning more branches, checks for out-of-capacity at each iteration of the loop, ...

---

None of the above examples are idiomatic, though.

Here is how I'd write them:

```
#[inline(never)]
pub fn extend_fill() {
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    v.extend(0u16..10000);
}
```

This method comes from implementing the [`Extend` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Extend%3CT%3E). When used with a trust length iterator (as this one), it will do a single "growth" step if necessary and then push without ever checking again.

The assembly is not as lean as `replace_fill`, but still looks pretty good:

```
example::extend_fill:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 64
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 24], 2
  xorps xmm0, xmm0
  movups xmmword ptr [rbp - 16], xmm0
  lea rdx, [rbp - 48]
  mov edi, 20000
  mov esi, 2
  call __rust_alloc@PLT
  test rax, rax
  je .LBB4_7
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 24], rax
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 16], 10000
  xor ecx, ecx
  movdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI4_0]
  movdqa xmm1, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI4_1]
  jmp .LBB4_2
.LBB4_6:
  movd xmm2, edx
  pshuflw xmm2, xmm2, 0
  pshufd xmm2, xmm2, 80
  movdqa xmm3, xmm2
  paddw xmm3, xmm0
  paddw xmm2, xmm1
  movdqu xmmword ptr [rax + 2*rcx + 32], xmm3
  movdqu xmmword ptr [rax + 2*rcx + 48], xmm2
  add rdx, 16
  mov rcx, rdx
.LBB4_2:
  movd xmm2, ecx
  pshuflw xmm2, xmm2, 0
  pshufd xmm2, xmm2, 80
  movdqa xmm3, xmm2
  paddw xmm3, xmm0
  paddw xmm2, xmm1
  movdqu xmmword ptr [rax + 2*rcx], xmm3
  movdqu xmmword ptr [rax + 2*rcx + 16], xmm2
  lea rdx, [rcx + 16]
  cmp rdx, 10000
  jne .LBB4_6
  mov qword ptr [rbp - 8], 10000
  mov rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 16]
  test rsi, rsi
  je .LBB4_5
  add rsi, rsi
  mov rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 24]
  mov edx, 2
  call __rust_dealloc@PLT
.LBB4_5:
  add rsp, 64
  pop rbp
  ret
.LBB4_7:
  movups xmm0, xmmword ptr [rbp - 40]
  movaps xmmword ptr [rbp - 64], xmm0
  movaps xmm0, xmmword ptr [rbp - 64]
  movups xmmword ptr [rbp - 40], xmm0
  lea rdi, [rbp - 48]
  call __rust_oom@PLT
  ud2
```

I encourage you to try it out, and in general get familiar with Rust Iterators: sweet code, good performance, they're a tool you'll need.

Comment: I would say that `let mut v: Vec<u16> = (0..10000).collect();` is more idiomatic.

Comment: @Hauleth: I didn't want to assume too much about the usecase. It's a very common scenario, for me, to reuse the same buffer over and over, in which case `clear` + `extend` is necessary. `collect` might work, `extend` just works.

Comment: "When in doubt, check the assembly!", not everyone want to learn assembly that why we write in rust ;).

Comment: @Stargateur: It was a bit tongue in the cheek; but it's also the only real answer. At the end of the day, it's way simpler to check the assembly than it is to divine what the optimizer could have (or not have) done with the original code.

Comment: How do you check assembly via the Playground? I haven't delved into that too much. Also, while I can see that the assembly is visibly more complicated, I wouldn't understand *why* unless I had read K. Biermann's comment on the original post.

Comment: As an aside, the `extend` option isn't *quite* as useful for me, since I was only using an incremented vector for the sake of testing (the actual puzzles require input read from `stdin`), but that's still an interesting approach. Should I ever need that in the future I'll have to keep it in mind.

Comment: @BHustus: If you are reading from `stdin`, can you read in small batches rather than one at a time? If you can, then reading a batch and extending by a batch is likely more efficient (for both operations) than reading one by one and pushing one by one.

Comment: @BHustus: As for reading the assembly, the trick is to skim. I don't understand half or even 3/4 of it. However I know what a label is (`.LBB4_2`), I know that any `jxxx .LBB4_2` is a jump and that any `call` is... a call :) The rest I piece together from there.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "reading a small batch". The boilerplate code I'm using creates a `String`, `read_line`s into the String, and then converts it into a number, then puts it in the Vector through some method.